# Code signing error, but looks fine in setup

Tags: ios7, xcode5, code-signing

I suddenly started receiving this error on my distribution builds:

```
Code Sign warning: Specified PROVISIONING_PROFILE (DBFBE0B4-B6DC-4AB7-909C-BE10988E0F7D) not found and no CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY specified. Ignoring PROVISIONING_PROFILE for now. This will become an error in the future.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
```

This error only occurs when I try to build for distribution. AdHoc compiles and runs fine. I suspected an expiry or something, but no such luck. I checked the build settings and they have a selected signing and provisioning cert for the AppStore build. And the selected profiles appear to be correct:

[image: This is correct?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an extremely obscure problem with my *Mac*, not Xcode. Due to problems while migrating from one machine to another, the security settings on the Library folder gained a new Permission, "Custom". This did not allow access to some of the files within, critically a plist that keychain uses to figure out where your user keychain is stored. Once the permissions on that file were fixed, Xcode was able to download the certs and off I went.

Answer (score 3):

1.Check project name, is it set to right target or not.

Select correct target and run.

Still having problem?

1.select project Navigator, Highlight project name,

2.select general, in that go to identity section check your team.

Once you have correct team, once again install your provisioning profile and certificate.

3.Go to build settings, code signing , select appropriate provisioning.

4.select correct target(means project name in tool bar section) and run.

Answer (score 1):

I had just now this exact problem.

The message is to say the least obscure. The error points to the Build Settings on the code signing, to either the Identity or the provisioning profile.

The reality was that the error was somewhere else, in the General, team setting, make sure you have the appropriate team selected, and xcode will be able to sort the rest out.